# How to list all files and folders in my dropbox using v2 api

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using Python SDK and would like to retrieve all of my dropbox files and folders.

I am using v2 of Python SDK of Dropbox.

```
dbx = Dropbox("DROBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN")
response = dbx.files_list_folder("/Apps/Marketing")
for file in response.entries:
    print file.name
```

However, I get an error:

```
dropbox.exceptions.ApiError: ApiError('b0479a07aaa5a9b405862ae75cbf135d', ListFolderError(u'path', LookupError(u'not_found', None)))
```

While Apps folder exists in Dropbox when I login (prob in root folder)

When I try to list with empty path in order to get root folder folders:

```
response = dbx.files_list_folder("")
```

the response entries are empty.

How can I retrieve the list of all files and folders in dropbox v2 api?

The token is the one I generated in OAuth 2 settings in dropbox.

and I gave the token App folder access to a folder under Apps called Marketing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I am using Python SDK and would like to retrieve all of my dropbox files and folders.
>   ...
>   and I gave the token App folder access to a folder under Apps called
>   Marketing.

You should have given your app **Full Dropbox** access type. With **App Folder** access type, your app is automatically restricted to the corresponding folder under `Apps`, and hence all paths passed to `files_list_folder()` running under that app are interpreted relative to your app's dedicated folder.

Comment: Right, but I have a folder under Apps which I want to retrieve its content. Why I can't retrieve it? I prefer to restrict access

Comment: @Dejell Is your "/Apps/Marketing" folder empty?

Comment: @Dejell will you retry running `response = dbx.files_list_folder("")` and confirm that the `response.entries` is empty.

Comment: no, my apps name is Marketing2Go, Marketing is the folder under Apps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135069/discussion-between-leon-and-dejell).

Answer (score 1):

```
dbx = Dropbox("DROBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN")
response = dbx.files_list_folder(path=DROPBOX_INPUT_PATH)
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a *large* number of files, a simple call to `dbx.files_list_folder()` will only return **a portion of** your files -- it returns only 500 files for me. In order to get all the remaining files, you can make use of a `cursor` along with the `dbx.files_list_folder_continue()` as follows:

```
dbx = get_dropbox_client()

folder_path = '' # root folder
all_files = [] # collects all files here
has_more_files = True # because we haven't queried yet
cursor = None # because we haven't queried yet

while has_more_files:
    if cursor is None: # if it is our first time querying
        result = dbx.files_list_folder(folder_path)
    else:
        result = dbx.files_list_folder_continue(cursor)
    all_files.extend(result.entries)
    cursor = result.cursor
    has_more_files = result.has_more
    
print("Number of total files listed: ", len(all_files))
print("All filenames: ", [entry.name for entry in all_files])
```