# Copy the entire Dropbox drive to local machine

Tags: python, dropbox

Is it possible to copy the entire Dropbox drive to local machine by Python?
The available code copy a specific folder and not the entire drive.

Comment: What available code?

Comment: Examples on the Internet let you copy a single folder or file to local machine, but not the entire drive.

Comment: What examples? Where are they? Can't you post links?

Comment: Visit this link please. [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51069637/file-migration-via-dropbox-api ] similar idea.

Comment: Och, so you are using a [dropbox api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python).

Comment: The dropbox api has a [list_folder](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/master/example/updown.py#L125) function, have you tried that.

Comment: Seems like this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085972/how-to-list-all-files-and-folders-in-my-dropbox-using-v2-api can list all folders inside a dropbox, just post `"/"` to the `files_list_folder` function

Comment: Kamil Cuk, thank you for the response. I will try it and post an update.

Answer (score 0):

list_folder function worked like a charm!. Thank you a lot Kamil Cuk.
Here is the code may it will help someone:

```
import requests
import json
url = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder"
headers = {
"Authorization": "Bearer INSERT YOUR ACCESS TOKEN HERE",
"Content-Type": "application/json"
}

data = {
  "path": ""
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: After list contents of the Dropbox drive,it's easy to copy it to local machine now.

Comment: By the way, you're not guaranteed to get all of the results from a single call to [/2/files/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder). You need to check the `has_more` value, and call back to [/2/files/list_folder/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue) if it's `true`, and so on. Refer to the [/2/files/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder) documentation for more information.